# Password change command via SSH using SSH.NET on z/OS

Tags: c#, ssh, zos, ssh.net

I'm looking to automate password change that's accomplished manually as such:

```
plink -ssh user@host changepass
user@host's password:
Access granted. Press Return to begin session.
Enter current password:
...
```

My understanding is that I am unable to accomplish this using `RunCommand` because it's not interactive and will not allow me to further specify the current password, hit enter, then the new password, etc.  From what I understand I would have to use `CreateShellStream` to emulate a shell.  When I try to do something like this:

```
using (var client = new SshClient(host, username, password))
{
    client.Connect();

    ShellStream shellStream = client.CreateShellStream(string.Empty, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    Console.Write(SendCommand("changepass", shellStream));
    
    client.Disconnect();
}
```

The result is `The command executed is invalid.....` which is the same thing that I get if I attempt to use plink without specifying the command inline:

```
plink -ssh -t user@host
Using username "user".
-- Pre-authentication banner message from server: ----------------------------
user@host's password:
Access granted. Press Return to begin session.
The command executed is invalid.....
```

I am wondering if my approach is invalid and whether this can be accomplished with SSH.NET.  If not what would be a good way to do this from C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server does not seem to support the "shell" channel, only the "exec" channel.

Indeed SSH.NET does not support providing an input to a command executed with the "exec" channel. See [Providing input/subcommands to a command (cli) executed with SSH.NET SshClient.RunCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57666090/850848)

Were it a *nix server, you might try to provide the input using input redirection.

```cs
client.RunCommand("echo input | command");
```

Though 1) this is not a safe way for passwords 2) I do not know a proper syntax for z/OS (or if it is even possible).

---

To allow providing the input properly, you would have to grab SSH.NET code and modify the `SshCommand` class to expose `IChannelSession.Write` the way `ShellStream.Write` does.

---

Or you will have to use a different library (I do not know other free good one than SSH.NET though). Or run an external tool like [PuTTY Plink](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) (I do not like that, but it's probably easiest way to go). See [Sending input during command output with SSH.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47263654/850848).